# Admin functionality for firebase linked app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two apps linked to my Firebase project. A customer app and an admin app. The purpose of the admin app is to control and manage the application data from the customer app.

However, i want the admin app to have a lot of restrictions like its own separate account creation and login functionality. I noticed that login credentials created with the customer app also works with the admin app. How do i ensure that the `auth` functionality for the admin app is secure, restricted and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Signing in to Firebase Authentication does nothing more than authenticate the user. It essentially verifies that you are Benny, and that you're not Frank.

Any permissions associated with a user come from other places. For example, if you use the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, you have server-side security rules that can enforce that the user can only access data that they're authorized for.

In your case you want to allow only some users to **use** the admin app. For that I'd consider [using custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). With this approach you add a custom claim to the profile of the admin users. This is simplest to do from a trusted environment with the Firebase Admin SDK. For example, in Node.js it is:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})
```

After running this code, the user identified by `uid` has a custom claim called `admin` with value `true` in their profile.

Now when a user signs in to your admin app, you can check for the presence of that `admin` claim and only allow them into the app when it's present. Of course you'll also want to check for the presence of the custom claim in any server-side actions that only admins are authorized for.

For more on this, also see:

- the video [five quick tips to secure your app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvLkkLjHdkw)
- the video [how to build a secure app in Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFlHzF5U-HA)
- the blog post [Controlling Data Access Using Firebase Auth Custom Claims](https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a)